# Timeline...for some users or for all?

Tags: discussion, new-features

Since a few minutes I saw that on the site there is the icon of the timeline to edit a question/answer. Is this available for all users?

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I was not sure if I was just hibernating too much. The time line is really there.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The most interesting part is the hibernating cat ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Never underestimate a cat! Especially when you want to make sure that the cat codes are working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all users, according to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/383578). This feature was (officially) introduced 12 minutes ago. Apparently it was a mod-only feature before.

Comment: The *button* may have been a mod feature, but the [post timeline has been available for some time as a "hidden feature"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64522/168244) by visiting `https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/{post_id}/timeline`.